# Restore rcdefaults by environment setting

Tags: python, bash, matplotlib

I have a library of python code that should create identical plots regardless of who is running it.  So I'd like to ignore any user settings from e.g. the `matplotlibrc` file.  I know I can do

`matplotlib.rcdefaults()`

within the code.  However there is no one module that I know every script (or future added script) will call.  I am able to define environment variables that will propagate through the bash environments that run these scripts, so is there is a way to specify matplotlib defaults that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one option might be to set

```
export MATPLOTLIBRC=some_empty_file
```